# Trouble achieving color over image effect

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image, and I used box-shadow to apply a blue color filter over the image. However, I can't seem to make the transparency any higher (the color is too transparent). Below are screenshots and the code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

How it looks now:
[image]

What I am trying to achieve:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class ="additional-container">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="additional" style="background-image:url('<?=$url?>');">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/rollup.png" />
    <span>Equity Zone One Pager</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional {
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 350px rgba(86, 159, 223, .9);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional span {
  padding: 15px;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional img {
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `spread-radius` value in the `box-shadow` property. It's a 4th value after the 2 offsets and blur radius:

> offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color
>
> box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

Try this:

```
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 350px rgba(86, 159, 223, .9);
```

You can see the difference here:

```css
.additional {
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 350px rgba(86, 159, 223, .9);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 45%;
  height: 40px;
}
.additional.spread {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 350px rgba(86, 159, 223, .9);
}
```

```html
<div class="additional">No Spread</div>

<div class="additional spread">With Spread</div>
```

[Box-Shadow @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Comment: That was my fault, I thought I had entered 0 0 0 350px, but I missed a 0 lol. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Use a pseudo element that is absolute positioned over the image, and give that element a transparent blue background.  For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="additional-container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nature-q-c-987-222-3.jpg"  />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.additional-container {
   position: relative;
}
.additional-container:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: rgba(66,161,224, 0.9);
 }
```

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s26397my/2/

Comment: I actually prefer this option as it doesn't rely on px values